# Bun Latest version is not getting installed in my Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bun

I try to run

```
npm install -g bun
```

But it's giving me this error in my terminal

`Unsupported platform for bun@1.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin,linux","arch":"arm64,x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Can anyone help me how can I install Bun on my Windows laptop? Thank you

A solution to install Bun

Comment: I think bun does not support windows at the moment. You might need WSL to work with bun in windows.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/43) for more details.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM yeah I think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bun does not support windows natively at the moment. You need to [install WSL](https://bun.sh/docs/installation#macos-and-linux) to work with bun in windows.

See also:

- [Windows Support](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/43)
- [Can't install bun on windows](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5247)

Answer (score -1):

It's an error from npm, so maybe it's some bug with bun as its in initial relases, however i would suggest clearing the npm cache and then upgrading npm with the following commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
npm install npm@latest -g
```

and then try installing bun again using the standard procedure. Lets hope it works, if it doesn't, maybe wait it out a day or two until enough people face this issue because the bun@1.0.1 released a few days ago.

UPDATE: Turns out you can use WSL on windows to run its container. It still not fully supported on windows yet.